# Is there a way I could listen to FM radio with my laptop but the radio comes from my android smartphone's built-in FM radio app?

Tags: fm-radio

Is there a way I could listen to FM radio with my laptop but the radio comes from my android smartphone's built-in FM radio app (which doesn't require internet)?

Something like a linking thing so that the sound of radio app from my phone will come out on my laptop instead.

Answer (score 4):

Just run a 3.5 mm audio cable from the headphone output of your phone to the microphone input of your laptop, then set up your laptop to play that audio (e.g. with the "Listen to this device" checkbox in Windows' sound device properties page). You need to have the cable there anyway, because it uses it for an antenna, so you might as well use the same cable for both purposes.

Comment: That easy I didn't think of it! My first thought went DLNA #D +1 for the obvious but invisible!